# Intellij IDEA, javascript error refuses to be ignored

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-14

I am using require js and Intellij keeps complaining on an error that I cannot simply ignore. It is annoying.

[image]

The thing is that the Intellij incorrectly assumes that this should be mapped to the local directory, whereas the path is not complete here.

How can I tell Intellij that it is not as Intelligent as it thinks it is and give me the developer the last word on this matter.

The path is dynamic and the server will look up this resource dynamically.

**It is not based on baseUrl either!**

This is quite annoying as well as several other errors Intellij keeps nagging about which are not really errors. This is true on HTML pages, CSS files, Javascript files.

Some errors you are just not able to ignore, which is quite bad.

**I wish all errors could be added to the Inspections list, which is not true at the moment.** This has resulted in me disabling Javascript and CSS completely because and error simply cannot be ignored. This is bad.

Right now, I am forced to do this to get rid of the error:

```
define.tmp = "Finance/services/FinanceService.js";
define([define.tmp], ...
```

Not pretty...

Comment: Right now module references ending with '.js' are reported, so as a workaround if it won't break your app you can remove file extension. In one of next 14.1 EAPs file references check will be moved from annotator to inspection and hence it will be possible to disable it.

Comment: @de1mar yes, however, it is required for my library. I am using 14.1 EAP. Maybe I have to wait a bit longer? What version?